How to setup datadog alerts without time intervals
I want to create a datadog alert when a specific phrase is found in my logs, however when I create a monitor with the specific query I need, I must specify over what time period I want the query evaluated (which causes one notification when the log is spotted, and another notification when the interval elapses without the same log being spotted again).
Is there a way to create a monitor such that when a specific log is spotted, I instantly get the first notification and not get any follow up notification?

You can use the conditional variables to send notification only during an alert and not during recovery.
https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notify/variables/?tab=is_alert#conditional-variables
A similar question - Datadog how do i change a monitor to a single alert with no recovery
